# Acoustic Echo Cancellation algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, echo, simulink, cancellation

My collegue and I are developping a sound and speech processing module on a Analog Device DSP. Because of the proximity of our single microphone and speaker, we have been experiencing some important echo. We want to implement an NLMS based algorithm to reduce this echo.

I first wanted to implement it and test the algorithm in Matlab but I am still having some issues. I think I might have some theoretical issue in my algorithm. I have a rough time understanding what would be the "desired signal" in the algorithm since I don't have access to a uncorrupted signal.

Here is an overview of my naive way to implement this in Matlab.
[Simulink diagram here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwAbJ6P-EcnKSk9faUkxSHFoSWs/view?usp=sharing)

[Link to Simulink code (.slx)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwAbJ6P-EcnKV0dDVTVVaktDQlk/view?usp=sharing)

Right now the code can't compile because of an "algeabric loop error" in Simulink, but I have a feeling there is more to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the documentation article about algebraic loops? http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/algebraic-loops.html

Comment: I might be completely misunderstanding your problem, but what do you mean you "don't have access to an uncorrupted signal"? Can't you just turn off the speaker and record an audio sample? Is your echo not literally the input from the microphone being also transmitted through the speaker with a little delay?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of model? Take a look at the algorithm picture at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra063/spra063.pdf which should help to model this.

Comment: Daniel, Yes I have read the documentation and I can't seem to find how to eliminate this algebraic loop.                     

Andras Deak, this has to be a real time process. So the microphone and speaker are always on. 

@Navan, I have posted a screenshot. Can't you see it in the link?

Answer (score 0):

The model you have is not fully correct. For acoustic echo cancellation you are using the adaptive filter to model the room. You are identifying the room characteristics using the adaptive filter. Once you do this you can then use your adaptive filter to identify the part of the far end signal from the loud speaker which goes back into the microphone and subtract that from the microphone signal to remove the echo.

For your adaptive filter your input should be the signal from far end which would be the signal going to the loud speaker in the room. Your desired signal is the signal coming out of the microphone in the room. The microphone signal contains signals from the voices from the person in the room and also a portion of sound from the loud speaker which is the echo.

```
Sound from far end          ----|In               | Out (You can ignore this)
                                | Adaptive Filter |
Sound from local microphone ----|Desired          | Error
```

In this model Error output signal from adaptive filter is your desired echo free signal. This is because error is computed by subtracting adaptive filter output from desired which is basically removing the echo.

To simulate this system in Simulink you need a filter to represent the room. You can use an ordinary FIR filter for this. You should be able to get room impulse responses online. These are usually long (~1000) slowly decaying impulse responses. Your audio source can represent signal from the loud speaker. You feed the same audio signal into this room response filter and you will get your desired signal. Feeding both into adaptive filter will make adaptive filter adapt to the room response filter.

Comment: Thank you very much Navan. This will most probably help me figure out my problem.

Comment: I realized that your implementation does not work out since the NLMS algorithm tends to adjust the FIR filter weights in order to reduce the error signal. In your case, we don't want the error signal to be reduced hence we get a weird result when the filter tries to adapt. 

Since the error is the output - desired and output in our case is the forecast echo, for this to work, wouldn't we need to put in the desired the actual echo? But I don't have access to such signal. 

Do you have another solution?

Comment: It does feel strange initially to look at this model since error signal is the signal you want. The assumption with this model is that there is no correlation with far end signal and near end signal. Even though the adaptive filter tries to minimize error it cannot go below removing echo because of the correlation assumption. What was the weird result?